# Filter rows in dataframe under group percentile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing various groups. For each group, I would like to filter out half of the rows, by their values - **I want to filter out the half of the rows with the lowest value column**. For example this is the base DF:

```
id  | groupId   | value 
1   | A         | 5
2   | A         | 10
3   | A         | 15
4   | A         | 9
5   | B         | 1
6   | B         | 2
7   | B         | 3
8   | B         | 4
```

*And after the filtering:*

```
    id  | groupId   | value 
    2   | A         | 10
    3   | A         | 15
    7   | B         | 3
    8   | B         | 4
```

You can see that the **bottom 50% of each group**, by their value, is filtered out.

Notice that 50% is a magic number and needs to be configurable.

Any idea how can I achieve this? I've tried groping by groupId and then get the mean but I couldn't figure it out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and custom function with [`DataFrame.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html):

```
p = 50
df = (df.sort_values(['groupId','value'])
        .groupby('groupId', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.tail(int(len(x) * (p / 100)))))
print (df)
   id groupId  value
1   2       A     10
2   3       A     15
6   7       B      3
7   8       B      4
```

Comment: Does p=75 will filter out 75% of my data or 25%?

Comment: @Dave I think it filter out 25%, if need 75% use `1 - int(len(x) * (p / 100))`